# Suggested readings for a beginner with Math backgroung

Tags: reference-request

Before asking any reference, I think it makes sense to give some feature of the recipient.

I am a pure mathematician. After the PhD I went to industry to work as software engineer. Recently I started being interested in finance; in the very beginning it was just to understand how to invest my savings, so I read "A Random Walk Down Wall Street". But afterwards I found myself very intrigued by the markets. Nevertheless, my understanding so far is something extremely simple, just the very basis that everyone has. Namely: if my business of chair-maker is going great, the word spreads so I got more inquiries than I can handle; so someone might decide to give me financial support to expand my business betting on the growth of my company: this person is buying some stock of my company, enjoying both loss and gains. I don't know anything more than that.
I know that through a broker I can buy stocks or ETFs, but I don't really know what's going on: when I go to the super marker and buy a banana, then I go to the cashier and pay for it. What does a broker do in practice is just obscure. I know that one can sell and buy stocks, but I know there are a lot of other financial products I don't know anything about.

On the other hand I know stochastic calculus. I miss what's in between. I would like to understand the structure of the markets, where do all those name like MSCI come from, approach portfolio theory and understand how the Black & Scholes formula is born: **NOT** mathematically, I want to understand what kind of observations of the real world led those guys to formulate it. I would love to understand why financial mathematics is so active producing al lot papers every year, but big institutions keep using B&S models.

Can someone direct me to some reading/other source of knowledge? Thank you.

Comment: This is a very general question and you'll have do a lot of reading to fill in all these holes. But, as general signposts, you might find "Capital Ideas" by Peter Bernstein and "Efficiently Inefficient" by Lasse Pedersen useful.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you want a quant finance book but without the math? I can propose a few good autobiographies by famous quants or biographies on these quants:

1. My Life as a Quant by Emanuel Derman - talks about an ex-physicist who went  into quant finance and worked at an investment bank in financial engineering. This is more related to the sell-side.
2. The Man Who Solved the Market by Gregory Zuckerman - discusses the rise of Jim Simons, the founder of one of the top quant funds in the world. This book is more relevant for the buy-side.
3. How I Became a Quant by Barry Schachter - talks about various famous quants in the industry currently.

Hopefully these books help you gain a better understanding of the quant finance world!

Answer (score 3):

In 1967 a mathematician named Ed Thorpe published a book with S. Kassouf in which it was suggested that a call option on 100 shares would in the short run make the same P&L as   $\lambda \cdot 100$ shares of the underlying, where $\lambda$ is a slowly varying number between 0 and 1 (which today we call Delta). Therefore if you knew or could somehow estimate $\lambda$ (the book did not say how) it was possible to neutralize or hedge the P&L from the call by being long the call and short the appropriate number of shares. Several people including of course Thorpe, but also Black, Scholes, Merton and perhaps Samuelson realized that the hedged position would earn $r_f$ in equilibrium (or just zero in the very short run in a low interest rate world) and so a formula for the Call price could be derived. In other words you should not make or lose money with this strategy if the call option price is "just right", but you could if the option price was too high or too low. Black and Scholes were the first to publish how to find this equilibrium price, though Merton was not far behind (and Thorpe also figured it out but he chose to keep it secret).

Ed Thorpe went over these events in some published articles.